# How do I get a count of this API data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a tags component that takes a count from data that's received from an API. the data looks like something like this:

```js
// Listing.js
const apiData = [
  { id: 1, billing_status: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', },
  { id: 2, billing_status: 'COMPLETED', },
  { id: 3, billing_status: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', },
  { id: 4, billing_status: 'NEEDS_CODING', },
  { id: 5, billing_status: 'NEEDS_INVOICING', },
  { id: 6, billing_status: 'NEEDS_CODING', },
  { id: 999, billing_status: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', },
]
```

I have a reusable component that I'm trying to construct an array that will resemble something like this while getting the count of all of the `billing_status`:

```js
// Listing.js
const keys = [
  { label: 'No Action Needed (3)', value: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', color: 'red' },
  { label: 'Needs Coding (2)', value: 'NEEDS_CODING', color: 'yellow' },
  { label: 'Needs Invoicing (1)', value: 'NEEDS_INVOICING', color: 'green' },
  { label: 'Completed (1)', value: 'COMPLETED', color: 'blue' },
]
```

and then passing that into a component that will render said information.

So far I'm passing an object into the reusable component, but i'm a little lost on how to proceed...

```js
// BillingList.js
const filterTags = {
  noActionNeeded: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED'
  //.... etc
}

<Listing keys={filterTags} />
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the problem,

First, you can get a count for yourself using the `Array.reduce` function.
Create a color map for the keys you are expecting.

Use the count and color map variable to get the keys list that you want.

```js
const apiData = [
  { id: 1, billing_status: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', },
  { id: 2, billing_status: 'COMPLETED', },
  { id: 3, billing_status: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', },
  { id: 4, billing_status: 'NEEDS_CODING', },
  { id: 5, billing_status: 'NEEDS_INVOICING', },
  { id: 6, billing_status: 'NEEDS_CODING', },
  { id: 999, billing_status: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', },
]


const keyMap = apiData
  .reduce((acc, {billing_status}) => ({
    ...acc,
    [billing_status]: (acc[billing_status] || 0) + 1
  }), {})

/*
{
  "NO_ACTION_NEEDED": 3,
  "COMPLETED": 1,
  "NEEDS_CODING": 2,
  "NEEDS_INVOICING": 1
}
*/

const colorMap = {
  "NO_ACTION_NEEDED": "red",
  "COMPLETED": "yellow",
  "NEEDS_CODING": "green",
  "NEEDS_INVOICING": "blue"
}

const keys = Object.keys(keyMap).map(key => ({
  label: `${key} (${keyMap[key]})`,
  value: key,
  color: colorMap[key]
}))

console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the variable part and the constant part. No need to create one array that includes both.

For example, the label and the color, which seem fixed for each status, so they could be a constant. Also, to make calling them easier, you can define it like this:

```
const STATUSES = {
  NO_ACTION_NEEDED: { color: 'red', label: 'No Action Needed' },
  ...
};
```

Now, all we need to do is compose the API data into a format that could be easily understood by the UI. Let's define the method for it:

```
const parseData = (apiData) => {
  const counts = apiData.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a[c.billing_status]) {
      a[c.billing_status]++;
    } else {
      a[c.billing_status] = 1;
    }
  }, {});

  this.setState({ counts });
};
```

Now, we can render it like this:

```
render() {
  const { counts } = this.state;

  ...
    {Object.keys(counts).map(key =>
      <div color={STATUSES[key].color}>{`${STATUSES[key].label} (${counts[key]})`}</div>
    }
  ...
}
```